# python check a list with another list

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching

I have two files:

```
file A:
U1
U2
U3
file B:
U1hjg 444 77 AGT
U8jha 777 33 AKS
U2jsj 772 00 AKD
U55sks 888 02 SJD
U3jsj 666 32 JSJ
```

Then I have two lists:

```
listA=open("file A").readlines()
listB=open("file B").readlines()
```

And I would like to check for each member of listA if it is present in List B, and print two files: one with the file B with matches (ordered by listA), and the other one with fileB without matches. 
Desired output:

```
file list_match:
U1hjg 444 77 AGT
U2jsj 772 00 AKD
U3jsj 666 32 JSJ

file list_unmatched:
U8jha 777 33 AKS
```

U55sks 888 02 SJD

I am a very beginner so I started trying this  as an example:

```
print(ListA[1])
print(ListB[2])

if ListA[1] in ListB[2]:
    print("yes")
```

And the output is:

```
U2
U2jsj 772 00 AKD
```

But the "yes" is not printed

But if I do:

```
if "U2" in ListB[2]:
    print("yes")
```

The output is:

```
yes
```

I do not understand where the error is. Could someone plese help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
st = set(list_b)

matches  = ([line for line in list_a if line  in st])
```

To get both:

```
# with will close your file automatically
with open("file A") as f1 ,open("file B")  as f2:
    st = set(f2) # get set of all lines in file b
    matches = []
    diff = []
    for line in f1: # iterate over every line in file a
        if line in st: # if line is in file b add it to our matches
            matches.append(line)
        else: # else add it to our diff list
            diff.append(line)
```

If you want to create two new files instead of appending to lists just write the lines.

```
with open("file A") as f1,open("file B") as f2,open("matches.txt","w") as mat ,open("diff.txt","w") as diff:
    st = set(f1) 
    for line in f2:
        if line in st:
            mat.write(line)
        else:
            diff.write(line)
```

You just need `ListA[1].rstrip() in ListB[2]` in your own example. There is a newline character at the end of `ListA[1]` and all lines excluding the last. 
If you `print(repr(ListA[1]))` you will see exactly what is there.

Printing our set and each line as we iterate you can see the newlines at the end:

```
{'U2\n', 'U3', 'U1\n'} <-st
#  print(repr(line)) on all lines from fileB
'file B:\n'
'U1hjg 444 77 AGT\n'
'U8jha 777 33 AKS\n'
'U2jsj 772 00 AKD\n'
'U55sks 888 02 SJD\n'
'U3jsj 666 32 JSJ'
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `readlines()` gives you the line with the `\n` terminating character. Hence, when you do

```
if ListA[1] in ListB[2]:
    print("yes")
```

you are essentially checking if `"U2\n"` is in `"U2jsj 772 00 AKD\n"`, which returns False. But since `"U2"` is in fact present, it prints `"yes"` when you use the literal.

You can verify the same in sample program below:

```
$ cat text.txt 
Sample
Text
Here.
$ cat test.py
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    print text
    print text[0]
$ python test.py
['Sample\n', 'Text\n', 'Here.\n']
Sample

$ #prompt
```

To correct this, if your file sizes are huge, strip the lines using `ListA[1].rstrip()`.

Else, you can use `.read()` and split on `"\n"`, create a list, and use a custom list comprehension method:

```
with open("file A") as f1 ,open("file B")  as f2:
    s1 = f1.read().split("\n")
    s2 = f2.read().split("\n")
    with open("matching.txt","w") as match, open("non-matching.txt","w") as no_match:
        matching = [x for x in s2 for y in s1 if y in x]
        non_matching = [x for x in s2 for y in s1 if y not in x]
        for line in matching:
            match.write(line)
        for line in non_matching:
            no_match.write(line)
```